How to migrate a public scoped package from Google Artifact Registry to NPM registry
I have published a scoped public package into Google Artifact Registry, now I would like to move this to NPM/Github Packages registry.
Is there any documentation or way on how to achieve this.
I have tried deleting the package from Google Artifact Registry, waited for 24hrs, and tried publishing after creating an account in npm. But it doesn't work.
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@org-scoped/xxx - Not found

